# Why can std::vector not accept iota_view iterators of type size_t?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, std-ranges

The following code fails to compile when `n` is `size_t` but works fine for `int` and `unsigned`.

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    size_t n = 1;
    auto view = std::ranges::iota_view{n, n};
    std::vector test(view.begin(), view.end()); //std::vector dislikes these iterators
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/a3eGeMWqh

Comment: Your linked example fails also for a `long` type. Looks like a g++ bug, to me. (Works fine in MSVC.)

Comment: size_t and log long are common used types for boost::irange / counting_iterator in our applications. Would be pity if iota_view can't replace them one way or the other (albeit with dropping singed integer support for difference type)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to solve the [issue of integer overflow](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1522r1.pdf), the difference type of `iota_view<uint64_t, uint64_t>::iterator` will be `__int128` in libstdc++, which is a [*integer-class type*](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.winc#2).

An iterator with *integer-class* difference type is [not a C++17 input iterator](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterators#concept:cpp17-input-iterator), so this makes `vector` template deduction fails because the iterator pair argument does not meet the requirements of *`__LegacyInputIterator`* (i.e. the difference type should only be a (signed) integral type).

It's worth noting that `__int128` is treated as integral type (which models `std::integral`) under GNU extensions, your code will be well-formed under the `--std=gnu++20` flag.

Answer (score 13):

I suppose it is indeed unspecified whether this deduction is allowed.

The deduction guide that you want to use here requires that the iterator is a (legacy) input iterator. It is (mostly) unspecified to what degree the implementation will verify this. It may or may not check the requirements listed in the standard. See [[container.requirements.general]/18](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/container.requirements.general#18) for details.

However one of the requirements is that `difference_type` is a "*signed integer type*" (or `void`), see [[iterator.iterators]/2.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/iterator.iterators#2.2).

On the other hand `iota_view`'s iterators are only specified to have a `difference_type` which is a *signed integer type* if such a type exists with a width larger than the width of the value type. This is typically not the case for `size_t`. In this case the standard only requires `difference_type` to be a "*signed-integer-like type*". See [[range.iota.view]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/range.iota.view#1) and [[sequence.reqmts]/13.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/sequence.reqmts#13.3) for details.

A *signed-integer-like type* may also be a non-integer type that behaves like one. But if a type is chosen that is not actually an integer type, then the iterator doesn't satisfy the *legacy* iterator requirements and therefore the requirements for the deduction guide would not be fulfilled.

You can inspect `std::begin(view)::difference_type` to see that GCC chose `__int128`, which behaves like an integer, but which the implementation doesn't consider an extended integer type (`std::is_integral_v<__int128>` is `false`).

GCC still gives the iterator a `std::input_iterator_tag` as `iterator_category` member, but going by the resolution of [LWG 3670](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#3670) that is supposed to be removed under these circumstances and that resolution also seems to indicate to me that the iterators of `std::iota_view` are really not supposed to be guaranteed to be legacy iterators in this situation. I don't know enough about this to be sure whether there is a defect here or not. It seems unfortunate to me if this is intended.

The same applies to the constructor itself as well, so specifying the template argument on `std::vector` will not resolve this either. See [[sequence.reqmts]/13.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/sequence.reqmts#13.1).

Comment: Apparently when `--std=gnu++2b` is used `std::is_integral_v<__int128>` is `true` and this code compiles.