std::reduce works with int-based ranges but not with long
I've been experimenting with C++ ranges and ran across a strange issue. I've been trying to calculate a sum of integer elements produced by a range using different methods. std::reduce seems to work just fine with a range producing ints, but with 64-bit longs I get a compilation error which I can't really comprehend.
Here's a simplified example:
#include <ranges>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
  auto v = std::views::iota(0l, 10l);
  auto s = std::reduce(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
  std::cout << "sum=" << s << '\n';
}

range2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
range2.cpp:7:8: error: deduced type ‘void’ for ‘s’ is incomplete
    7 |   auto s = std::reduce(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
      |        ^
In file included from range2.cpp:3:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14/include/g++-v14/numeric: In instantiation of ‘constexpr typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::value_type std::reduce(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = ranges::iota_view<long int, long int>::_Iterator; typename iterator_traits<_Iterator>::value_type = void]’:
range2.cpp:7:23:   required from here
    7 |   auto s = std::reduce(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14/include/g++-v14/numeric:345:25: error: invalid use of void expression
  345 |       return std::reduce(__first, __last, value_type{}, plus<>());
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This code works however if the range produces 32-bit integers: auto v = std::views::iota(0, 10);, or if I use
std::accumulate(std::begin(range), std::end(range), 0l) or std::ranges::fold_left(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0l, std::plus<long>() to compute the sum. std::reduce also works correctly on traditional containers like std::vector<long>.
I'm guessing something fails with the deduction of the result type. Supplying more explicit parameters to std::reduce trying to coerce it to use long produces a different error message:
auto s = std::reduce(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0l, std::plus<long>());
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14/include/g++-v14/numeric: In instantiation of ‘constexpr _Tp std::reduce(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _Tp, _BinaryOperation) [with _InputIterator = ranges::iota_view<long int, long int>::_Iterator; _Tp = long int; _BinaryOperation = plus<long int>]’:
range2.cpp:7:23:   required from here
    7 |   auto s = std::reduce(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0l, std::plus<long>());
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14/include/g++-v14/numeric:291:21: error: static assertion failed
  291 |       static_assert(is_invocable_r_v<_Tp, _BinaryOperation&, _Tp&, __ref>);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14/include/g++-v14/numeric:291:21: note: ‘std::is_invocable_r_v<long int, std::plus<long int>&, long int&, void>’ evaluates to false
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14/include/g++-v14/numeric:292:21: error: static assertion failed
  292 |       static_assert(is_invocable_r_v<_Tp, _BinaryOperation&, __ref, _Tp&>);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14/include/g++-v14/numeric:292:21: note: ‘std::is_invocable_r_v<long int, std::plus<long int>&, void, long int&>’ evaluates to false
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14/include/g++-v14/numeric:294:21: error: static assertion failed
  294 |       static_assert(is_invocable_r_v<_Tp, _BinaryOperation&, __ref, __ref>);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/14/include/g++-v14/numeric:294:21: note: ‘std::is_invocable_r_v<long int, std::plus<long int>&, void, void>’ evaluates to false

I'm using GCC 14.2.1 on Linux 64-bit. I tried the example on Compiler Explorer, and various compiler versions give me a similar error.
Am I dealing with some library bug here? The only similar error I could find is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95833, but that one was resolved years ago.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/78428407 tl;dr the difference_type of that iota_view iterator does not satisfy the legacy iterator requirements

..Which in turn is addressed in C++23 by P2408

Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74134350/why-can-stdvector-not-accept-iota-view-iterators-of-type-size-t/74134946#74134946
